# C++ delete an item from pointers array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sfml, delete-operator

I am creating an array of pointers and then tryin to delete one of the items this way :

```
sf::Rect<float>* Rects2[] ={new sf::Rect<float>(0,0,WIDTH,1), (sf::Rect<float>*)&_invader.getBoundingRect() };
    delete Rects2[1];
```

When i run the code, I get a debug assertion failed with "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)"

I tried with no success to delete the element using `delete &Rects2[1];`

when I tried to delete the first item - `delete Rects2[0];` i got the error once, and then it went fine.

Comment: אתה לא משתמש בפקודה בצורה נכונה נסיך של אבא

Answer (score 0):

Your second array element isn't allocated by you, so you should not attempt to de-allocate it (unless the library documentation says so).

As for the other attempt, of course you can only de-allocate a thing once.

Comment: the second element is allocated by a class i made. it simply return a sf::Rect<float>.
And about the first element - the delete called only once. i ran the code 4 times and only the first time gave this error, and after that it went ok